# React functional component state with external callback

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional React component that, among other things, sets up a Bluetooth connection and sets a `device` variable. It also sets up a callback listener for when Bluetooth responses come in. The listener needs to access `device`.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [device, setDevice]... ?
  var deviceVar;
  
  const listener = (data) => {
    // needs device
    console.log(device, deviceVar);
    // 'device' is undefined but 'deviceVar' is correct
  }

  const scan = () => {
    setDevice(...);
    device = ...
    addListener(listener)
  }  
}
```

Using `setState` is unreliable because the listener is triggered before (i.e.) `device` was updated.

What is the correct way to handle this? Is there a more functional/hooks approach?

Note that this question is NOT about using `useEffect` to provide my own callback on `device`. It is about an 'external' callback that I can't control the timing of.

Comment: Can you update your question with more details on how you're connecting your device and how `addListener` is implemented? Also, `device = ...` would be an anti-pattern, as you should be using `setDevice` instead.

Comment: Yes, I know `device = ...` is an anti-pattern, this is what I'm trying to fix

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is race condition on updating the `device` state, then adding subscription in separate `useEffect` triggered on device change can help:

```
export default function App() {

  const [device, setDevice] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     // called after device is updated in "scan"
     addListener(listener);
  }, [device])
  
  const listener = (data) => {
    // needs device
    console.log(device);
  }

  const scan = () => {
    // update device
    setDevice(...);
  }  
}
```

Comment: The part that's confusing me is that I need to be able to immediately access `device` in the same function that sets it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, I think you can do the following:

```
export default function App() {

  const listener = (device, data) => {
     console.log(device);
  }

  const scan = () => {
     const device = ...;
     addListener(data => listener(device, data));
  }  
}
```